# Wavefront of a cylindrical beam of light

Tags: optics, refraction, huygens-principle

The given question states that a cylindrical beam of light with refractive index of the beam varying as u=A+B/r^2 where r is the distance form the axis of the beam. Now the questions asks us the shape of the wavefront of the beam. The answer of the question simply states that as it is a cylindrical beam initially it will remain planar.
Now when I thought about this question, I formulated that since y=Asin(wt+kx) for any wave and a wavefront is simply a collection of point with the same phase.The term (wt) varies only on the frequency of the wave which is common for all, but kx varies inversely as lambda. And Lambda varies as the speed which varies with the refractive index. Therefore there should be some function of x which satisfies them and it cannot be simply a planar surface. Where have I or the solution gone wrong could somebody tell me?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "beam...with refractive index of the beam". That makes no sense. Light does not have a refractive index, materials do.

Comment: @JoséAndrade Light does have a refractive index, its very evident in the splitting of light by a prism.